# Google action status is deployed but unable to access from other device

Tags: actions-on-google

My google action status is 
[deployed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gdKc.png)

But I'm still unable to access this from any other device than my own
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

On which phase you have deployed ??? as an alpha version or beta version. 
If you have deployed on alpha version then you have to add mail ids of testers who you are willing to give a try on your action. And once you add those mail ids send the alpha test link which will be seen in **manage alpha testers** tab. This link is called opt link try to open that link on same mail id which you have added in as alpha testers. **And make sure that your google assistant account is on same mail id which you have added as alpha tester first and then open that opt-in link.**

Comment: I can't determine if it's an alpha test or beta test, but it says the deployed channel is Production, I guess that means it's not deployed in any test phase. I'm still not sure if that's the case. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Once deployed, it can take a few hours for it to be available on all devices. If you're still having problems, we'd need a lot more to help you diagnose them, but StackOverflow probably isn't the best forum to do so since this doesn't sound like a coding problem. Instead, you should try posting your question [on the support forum at Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/) or [send a message to support](https://developers.google.com/assistant/support).

Comment: Thank you, I'll contact the support